# Can't give quick reply options to twitter user using tweepy (Python)

Tags: python, twitter, chatbot, tweepy

I want to send a direct message with quick reply option in Python using the Tweepy library and Twitter's API. The Tweepy documentation says that I can send DMs with quick reply options by using the following code:

```
API.send_direct_message(recipient_id, text[, quick_reply_type][, attachment_type][, attachment_media_id])
```

I tried implementing this by creating my own options using Python, this is how I implemented it:

```
import tweepy
import time

#login credentials need to be filled here
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('','')
auth.set_access_token('', '')

api = tweepy.API(auth)


user = api.get_user("user's name")


options = [
            {
              "label": "I'm good",
              "description": "It means you're doing good",
              "metadata": "external_id_1"
            },
            {
              "label": "Not so good",
              "description": "It means you're not doing good",
              "metadata": "external_id_2"
            }
          ]
direct_message = api.send_direct_message(user.id, "Hey Man! How's it going?", quick_reply_type=options)
```

I end up getting this error:

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 214, 'message': 'event.message_create.message_data.quick_reply: Unknown quick_reply type '}]
```

I even tried making the options into Python Objects and make it JSON serializable but it still ends up giving the same error. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a know bug in Tweepy, already identified and fixed (see Pull Request on [Github](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/1364)), but not yet available.

Until it is merged the only option seems to be to fix Tweepy locally and use the customised version.

Comment: Ah didn't know it was a bug. I'll try to fix it locally then. Thanks.